# How to solve sin(z)=2 in Sympy?

Tags: python, equation, solver, sympy

Sympy works with complex numbers, therefore there is possibility to solve equations like `sin(z)=2`. However, I cannot work it out. Anyone has an idea how to solve it in Sympy?

BTW, the solution has form like following:

`z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\ln(2\pm\sqrt{3})i`

[image: <code>z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\ln(2\pm\sqrt{3})i</code>]

I will add a very specialized method to solve this problem in Sympy, which can hardly be genralized:

```
from sympy import *
z=symbols('z')
r=re(sin(z)-2)
i=im(sin(z))
x,y=symbols('x,y',real=True)
eq1=r.subs({re(z):x,im(z):y})
eq2=i.subs({re(z):x,im(z):y})
solve((eq1,eq2),(x,y))
```

The output is `[(pi/2, log(-sqrt(3) + 2)), (pi/2, log(sqrt(3) + 2))]`. Anyone has a better solution?

Comment: I doubt this is possible to be honest :( I at least don't have the knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer the `log` format, use `.rewrite(log)`, like

```
In [4]: asin(2).rewrite(log)
Out[4]:
      ⎛  ___        ⎞
-ⅈ⋅log⎝╲╱ 3 ⋅ⅈ + 2⋅ⅈ⎠
```

Combining this with Games's answer, you can get:

```
In [3]: sols = solve(sin(z) - 2, z)

In [4]: sols
Out[4]: [π - asin(2), asin(2)]

In [5]: [i.rewrite(log) for i in sols]
Out[5]:
⎡         ⎛  ___        ⎞        ⎛  ___        ⎞⎤
⎣π + ⅈ⋅log⎝╲╱ 3 ⋅ⅈ + 2⋅ⅈ⎠, -ⅈ⋅log⎝╲╱ 3 ⋅ⅈ + 2⋅ⅈ⎠⎦
```

And by the way, there are really infinitely many solutions, because `sin` is `2*pi` periodic. SymPy currently doesn't support giving all of them directly, but it's easy enough to get them by using `sin(z + 2*pi*n)` instead of `sin(z)`:

```
In [8]: n = Symbol('n', integer=True)

In [9]: sols = solve(sin(z + 2*pi*n) - 2, z)

In [10]: sols
Out[10]: [-2⋅π⋅n + asin(2), -2⋅π⋅n + π - asin(2)]

In [11]: [i.rewrite(log) for i in sols]
Out[11]:
⎡              ⎛  ___        ⎞                    ⎛  ___        ⎞⎤
⎣-2⋅π⋅n - ⅈ⋅log⎝╲╱ 3 ⋅ⅈ + 2⋅ⅈ⎠, -2⋅π⋅n + π + ⅈ⋅log⎝╲╱ 3 ⋅ⅈ + 2⋅ⅈ⎠⎦
```

Here `n` is any integer.

Comment: This form is a little different from yours because it has an `I` inside the log. You can play with functions like `expand_complex` to get it to a more standard form if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Well you need to set it like this

```
sin(z) - 2 = 0
```

So like this:

```
>>> from sympy.solvers import solve
>>> from sympy import *
>>> z = Symbol('z')
>>> solve(sin(z) - 2, z)
[pi - asin(2), asin(2)]
>>> asin(2).evalf()
1.5707963267949 - 1.31695789692482*I
```

Comment: Then what is `asin(2)`, how to obtain the form of it?

Comment: @kattern Its `arcsin(2)`. You can get the value using `.evalf`.

Comment: I'm not good in math but `sin(z) = 2` looks wrong since the range of `sin` is `[-1, 1]`, there should not be a real solution.

Comment: @BSH How about you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html). Because this is a valid solution to the problem, actually. Because if sin(z) = 2, then arcsin(2) = z. Is it really that simple, and the `pi - arsin(2)`, is simply because its a sinuous graph.

Comment: @BSH Not a real one, no. But the question is explicitly about complex ones.

Comment: I want a solution like in the updated question, how to obtain that solution. Sorry, I do not know how to add Tex equation in the question.

Comment: @glglgl This is imaginary solution, I first know about it, +1.

Comment: @BSH How is the Tex equation added? I still has no idea.

Comment: @kattern You can use [codecogs](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), write your code and go down you will see HTML code copy the image url: `...<img src="[copy the image url from here]" ...`.

Comment: What version of SymPy are you using? For me, in the latest version, I don't get any solutions.